# Run an Android VM on a ubuntu server, and remotely access it

Tags: server, virtualization, android, remote-access

I can't find anything related to what I'm looking for

Found this : [github.com/DeviceFarmer/stf][1]
but not what I looking for

any tips to guide my research?
[1]: https://github.com/DeviceFarmer/stf

Comment: Have you looked at the Android SDK?

Comment: Googling "How to run Android on QEMU" returns many useful hits. Simply substitute your preferred VM application.

Comment: thx @user535733, i thinks u help me a lot on this, i will look deeper on QEMU

Comment: check this out, I am running successfully: How to Run Android on Linux Using Virtual Machine https://beebom.com/run-android-on-linux-using-virtual-machine/ A pre-made VM disk image(Android-x86 9.0-R2 Pie) is downloadable on this page : https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  A heads-up that you shouldn't add "SOLVED" to questions here.  AU isn't like "forums" or "discussion sites" you may be used to -- We're a question-and-answer site. If you have found the answer through a Google search, please post it as an *answer* and self-accept it.  You can credit @user535733 in the answer for pointing you in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run an Android emulator (VM) is to install [AndroidStudio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) and then the emulator will be installed.

Here's mine running on Ubuntu 22.04 after starting it from AndroidStudio Tools...Device Manager...

[image: android emulator]

Remotely accessing that Android Emulator is going to be far trickier.

Although you can probably set up a way to remote to your Ubuntu machine and then run the emulator from there.

Comment: ''On a ubuntu server'', and  u tell me to run graphical things ?

Answer (score 0):

Use VirtualBox with a Android-x86 VM image disk file.

1. setting up VirtualBox on the Ubuntu instance,
2. get an Android image: A pre-made VM disk image(Android-x86 9.0-R2 Pie) is downloadable on this page : https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/
3. config the VM as detailed here: How to Run Android on Linux Using Virtual Machine https://beebom.com/run-android-on-linux-using-virtual-machine/